# important static file to webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I was exploring a react project in github.

I don't understand these in app.js

```
import 'file?name=[name].[ext]!../manifest.json';
import 'file?name=[name].[ext]!../.htaccess';
import 'file?name=[name].[ext]!../favicon.ico';
import 'file?name=[name].[ext]!../favicon.png';
```

starting from line 11, https://github.com/mxstbr/login-flow/blob/master/js/app.js

Comment: Did you do anything to help you understand it? E.g. did you search for and read some documentation? If yes, what is still unclear? If not, why not?

Comment: @FelixKling I don't know whether it is es6 or part of webpack. I only know you can `import React from 'react'`

Comment: It's definitely webpack. ES6 doesn't actually define the structure of a module identifier. I.e. what is inside the string is completely up to the *module loader* (in this case webpack). What you see is webpack's file loader at play: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Answer (score 0):

It's using webpack's [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader).

`file-loader` usually loads a file as it is. It is then put in the webpack output as `<md5hash>.<extension>`. If you specify `name=[name].[ext]` as a query string parameter to `file-loader`, the output filename will be the same as the original filename.

So, all in all, it is a way to ensure that a file is copied to the webpack output, but not modifying it in any way, including the file name.